# SSIS Conditional Split Not Working as Expected

Tags: ssis, conditional-split

I have the following Conditional Split set

```
Not Posted :  O_Variance != 0 && O_L_Revenue_nSAP == 0
Need Investigating : O_Variance != 0 && O_L_Revenue_nSAP != 0
Posted : O_Variance == 0
```

And everything is going to Posted even when the condition isn't meet and I have no idea why.

Comment: What is the priority in each condition in your configuration?

Comment: The order as listed above

Comment: what is the source of your data and what type are O_Varience and O_L_Revenue_nSAP ?

Comment: Data is from OLE DB with some derived columns etc, the Data Type for those fields is numeric

Comment: Can you show your flow and detail what are you doing in each component so we can help you